# How to get length of find() results with MongoDB\Driver query in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a MongoDB server with a collection counting hundreds of thousands of documents.

I need to get only the number of documents matching the query filter condition using MongoDB\Driver in PHP.

In `mongo-shell` I would simply do the following:

```
db.samples.find({"location": {$geoWithin: {$geometry: ...reference_polygon... }}}).length
```

The below query in PHP would return a cursor with the full list of the documents (could be thousands of docs) which I don't need, I'm only looking for the number of the samples within a specified polygon:

```
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query( 
    ["location" => ['$geoWithin' => ['$geometry' => $reference_polygon]]],
    []
);
$cursor = $dbm->executeQuery("test.samples", $query);
```

Even reducing projection to return a single field as `_id` would significantly increase the calculation time.

Is there any way to get just a scalar number of documents and avoid loading cursor results and then counting it like `count($cursor->toArray())`?

MongoDB Server: 4.4.1
PHP version: 7.4
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally, I found a way to do it using `MongoDB\Driver\Command`.

The code is below, would someone have a better proposal, please feel free to comment.

```
$database_name = "test";
$collection_name = "samples";
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query( 
    ["location" => ['$geoWithin' => ['$geometry' => $reference_polygon]]],
    []
);
$dbc = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(
    ['count' => $collection_name, "query" => (object)$query]
);
$cursor = $dbm->executeCommand($database_name, $dbc);
$n = (isset($cursor->toArray()[0]->n)) ? $cursor->toArray()[0]->n : 0;
```